# Is it possible to set uitabbar on left side of screen?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

so, question is in the title: Is it possible to set uitabbar on left side of screen not at the  bottom? thx=)

Comment: The Apple iOS human interface guideline docs state that a tab bar must go at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend to rotate the view of UITabBarController, because you need fix a lot problems, such as rotation of tabbar items, the size of tabbar, the size and rotation of tabbar content view.

Why not create a view or a view controller to custom what you need?

But, if you have to use a UITabBarController, you should rotate `[UITabBarController tabBar]` instead of `[UITabBarController view]`, because `the views` of `[UITabBarController viewControllers]` are subviews of `[UITabBarController view]`.

After rotating the `[UITabBarController tabBar]`, fix these:

1. rotation of the items in `[UITabBarController tabBar]`
2. size of `[UITabBarController tabBar]`
3. size of `UITabBarController` content view (you need to enumerate the subviews of `UITabBarController.view.subviews` to find out)

Comment: thx for answering! look plz here (yadi.sk/d/xsLWlWSrA7qj2) what i want to do... generally is it possible do so?..

Comment: I would use a Collection view

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to accomplish this, I would create a UITabBarController and rotate its view by 90 degrees.

Use code like this in `- viewDidLoad`:

```
CGFloat radiansForRotation = -90.0 * (M_PI / 180.0); // radians = degrees * (pi/180)
CGAffineTransform rr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radiansForRotation);
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.view.transform, rr);
```

Comment: thx for answering! look plz here (yadi.sk/d/xsLWlWSrA7qj2) what i want to do... generally is it possible do so?..